# Javers findshadows returns null in child object & some fields of parent object

Tags: javers

i have the following two domain objects and it has the  one to many relation between them 
    1.BOY (Boy.java)
    2.CYCLE (cycle.java)
    its a springboot based application,and i did javerse repository implementation with this application .

while fetching the shadows using JQL [javerse query language ] its not working properly

1.Pom  file  i added javers-spring-boot-starter-sql dependency

2.Boy entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "boy")
public class Boy implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "boy")
private Set<Cycle> cycles = new HashSet<>();
}
```

3.Cycle entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cycle")
public class Cycle implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "cycname")
private String cycname;

@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnoreProperties("cycles")
private Boy boy;
}
```

4.Boy and Cycle  repositories has been annotated with @JaversSpringDataAuditable

6.Audit Fetch API using Javerse Query Language

```
    @PostMapping("/audit/shadowsboy/{id}")
    @Timed
    public String getShadows(@PathVariable Long id) {


        JqlQuery queryBuilder = QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(id, Boy.class).withScopeCommitDeep().build();
        List<Shadow<Object>> shadowList = javers.findShadows(queryBuilder);
        System.out.println("shadows: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::" + javers.getJsonConverter().toJson(shadowList));

        return javers.getJsonConverter().toJson(shadowList);
    }
```

Output: 
after adding a cycle to boy ,findShadows by Boy id returns

```
{
"commitMetadata": {
"author": "anonymousUser",
"properties": [],
"commitDate": "2019-07-20T13:11:24.076",
"commitDateInstant": "2019-07-20T07:41:24.076Z",
"id": 2.00
},
"it": {
"id": 951,
"name": null,
"cycles": []
}
},
{
"commitMetadata": {
"author": "anonymousUser",
"properties": [],
"commitDate": "2019-07-20T13:04:26.988",
"commitDateInstant": "2019-07-20T07:34:26.988Z",
"id": 1.00
},
"it": {
"id": 951,
"name": "gajendran.g",
"cycles": []
}
}
]
```

expected outcome : cycles object must not be empty or null

Comment: Is this a [mcve]?

Comment: yes ,its simple two classes has parent and child relation ,and i tried  findShadows but its not works properly

Comment: A [mcve] would have a `main`, I think, if my knowledge of Java suffices.

Comment: +1 @wizzwizz4 ,
gajendrangnanasekarangajendra try to write a failing test case like these 
https://github.com/javers/javers/tree/master/javers-core/src/test/groovy/org/javers/core/cases